# Как мониторить нагрузку сразу нескольких серверов?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, мониторинг, нагрузочное-тестирование

У меня есть 40 серверов на Linux (Ubuntu 22). Мне нужно видеть их загруженность ядер, оперативной памяти. И нужно чтобы все эти параметры были отображены на одном экране (по всем 40 серверам), чтобы я мог видеть где какой нагружен а какой не очень в один и тот же момент времени.

Может быть есть какие-то программы на windows?

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: Программа на windows называется Chrome. С её помощью смотрят на какую-либо систему мониторинга, например, на Zabbix.

Comment: +1. ещё можно назвать ganglia, collectd, munin, monit и т.п. Настраиваем на одном компе - приложение сервер, на остальные раскидываем агентов - и в дальнейшем смотрим и следим за нагрузкой из любого браузера.